# Rewrite URL term(s) separated by equal sign to query string(s)

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Using mod_rewrite, what RewriteRule(s) would make the following two examples function properly?

**Example #1** *(one term):*

```
http://example.net/dir/thanks
-to-
http://example.net/dir/index.php?a=thanks
```

**Example #2** *(two terms):*

```
http://example.net/dir/thanks=stackoverflow
-to-
http://example.net/dir/index.php?a=thanks&b=stackoverflow
```

> *Note:* The .htaccess file is located in /dir/ outside of domain root.

I've gotten close with this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)=([^/]*)/?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2 [L]
```

However, to work with example #1 a trailing "=" is required (which I want to avoid).  I've tried changing "=" to "=?" in the regex to make it optional but while it then works for example #1 it fails for example #2.

Thank you kindly for any consideration to my question.  I'm new to mod_rewrite and regex and am truly stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two main approaches:

**1.** More safer/easier to understand and extend if necessary. **Make two rules**: 1st will catch `thanks=stackoverflow` while 2nd will work with `thanks` only:

```
RewriteEngine On

# do not do anything for already existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .+ - [L]

# will work with /thanks=stackoverflow
RewriteRule ^([^/=]+)=([^/=]+)/?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2 [L]
# will work with /thanks
RewriteRule ^([^/=]+)/?$ index.php?a=$1 [L]
```

**2**. **Combine those two rules into a single rule**. In this case parameter `b=` will always be present, but will be empty for `thanks` scenario:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/=]+)(=([^/=]+))?/?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$3 [L]
```

*Tested both -- working fine on my Apache box.*

Comment: Thank you!  Both of your examples are working great here, too.  I really appreciate the detailed solutions; they've helped improve my understanding of mod_rewrite.  After hours of throwing darts at my problem I now see where I was going wrong thanks to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create two seperate rewrite rules:

i) One that takes care of example 1 - with the added check that it does not contain an equal sign [so that you don't match example 2 with rewrite rule 1]

ii) Another one that takes care of example 2

Comment: Thanks for the helpful insight towards a solution.  I've accepted LazyOne's answer as it included working code but you helped steer me in the right direction initially.